# How can I run NPM without sudo?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I've been reading posts, trying to figure out how to run `npm install` without `sudo`. I also came across the following article but I think it's for an older version of NPM. I done the following which produced less errors, but still throw errors at the end:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

The only way I can get no errors is to run `sudo npm install` but I read this is not a good idea.

Below is the out I see after running it. My guess is permissions but I don't really know what folders I should chown (if at all). Sorry about the huge amount of data, I don't really know what is relevant. I couldn't see anything helpful in the log either (/var/www/budget/npm-debug.log) although it is huge. Is there anything I still need to chown?

```
$ npm install
npm WARN package.json budget@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN package.json budget@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json budget@0.0.1 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-less
.
.
.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk/1.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/bl/test/test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/budget
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/bl/test/test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/bl/test/test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid'
npm ERR! error rolling back  request@2.51.0 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/node-uuid' }
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing request@2.51.0
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/lib/utils.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/budget
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/lib/utils.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/qs/lib/utils.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/lib/util.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/budget
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/lib/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/lib/util.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/budget
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
grunt-cache-breaker@1.0.1 node_modules/grunt-cache-breaker
└── cache-breaker@0.0.4 (lodash@2.2.1)

grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3 node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch
├── tiny-lr@0.0.4 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3, qs@0.5.6)
└── gaze@0.4.3 (globule@0.1.0)

grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── which@1.0.8
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── async@0.1.22
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── exit@0.1.2
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.1)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)

grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.10.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.7, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── clean-css@2.2.22 (commander@2.2.0)
└── maxmin@0.2.2 (figures@1.3.5, pretty-bytes@0.1.2, chalk@0.5.1, gzip-size@0.2.0)

grunt-contrib-less@0.7.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-less
├── grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1 (zlib-browserify@0.0.1)
└── less@1.4.2 (mime@1.2.11, mkdirp@0.3.5, ycssmin@1.0.1)
npm ERR! Error: Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!     at errorHandler (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:80:16)
npm ERR!     at save (/usr/share/npm/lib/install.js:329:12)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install.js:98:7
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install.js:188:5
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:119:5
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:233:14
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/nodejs/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:233:14
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/lib/nodejs/slide/lib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:233:14
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/budget
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/mime-types/lib/mime.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/budget
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/mime-types/lib/mime.json
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/mime-types/lib/mime.json
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/images/logo.png'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/budget
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/images/logo.png
npm ERR! fstream_path /var/www/budget/node_modules/grunt-contrib-less/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/images/logo.png
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/budget/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to run commands like `npm install -g protractor` without using sudo you need to

- Configure NPM to copy package files to, and execute from a location that doesnt require `sudo` permissions (I believe the only place in Ubuntu which allows this by default is `/home/user-name/`)
  .
- Update the $PATH variable that BASH looks to when determining what scripts/programs are available to run from a command prompt

#### First need to establish where node is currently configured to install global packages

Based on  [NPM official config docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) - as well as various other sources
run:

```
$ npm config get prefix
```

or

```
$ npm config list
```

or (to show all config defaults)

```
$ npm config ls -l
```

#### NPM **prefix value** determines where node packages are installed.

In other words, if the result of running  `npm config list` looks like this:

```
; userconfig /home/michael/.npmrc
prefix = "/home/michael/npm"
```

It means

- you have a user level config `/home/michael/.npmrc` that NPM will parse **with higher priority than the global/system config file**
- that when you specify a global install `npm install -g protractor` protractor files will be installed into  `/home/michael/npm`

Now make the changes!

set the `prefix` directly by using :

```
npm config set prefix ~/npm
```

### Getting the NPM package script files into BASH's path

append (edit) the `.bashrc` file with:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/npm/bin"
```

and run

```
$ source .bashrc
```

to re-parse the `.bashrc` script

Comment: That done it, thanks. I recall having had to do something similar for RVM as I already had `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin`. My .bashrc file now has `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$HOME/.npm/bin` and I set prefix to "~/.npm".

Comment: awesome, yes `~/.npm` is a good way too - so you dont see npm folder in home path

Answer (score 2):

From the logs it seems you have your application stored in `/var/www/budget`, you `cwd` into this directory and run `npm install`. However, this path is most commonly owned by the Apache service user (*apache* or *httpd*, not sure which one exactly, it might also depend on the software you use).

**I do not recommend** taking ownership of this folder to your user account. However, it might be quite ok to put your user account into the *apache* user group and change the permissions so that the group has read/write access (if it already has not):

(make sure that the group is really *apache* before executing, lest you would give r/w permissions to some other group)

```
sudo chmod -R g+r,g+w /var/www
```

In general, you have allowed yourself to install npm modules globally (into */usr/local*, with the `-g` flag), but your application does not reside within that directory, so you must decide the best course of action to amend the permission settings for that particular application's path.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing in my opinion is to use a version manager, such as [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) or [n](https://github.com/tj/n).
This way you can have different versions of node installed and switch between them easily, and the executables will be stored under a different PATH, in case of nvm in `~/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin`, thus no sudo is needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

one risky way, go to /etc/sudoers & add this line at the end:

```
USERNAME HOSTNAME = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/npm
```

USERNAME - the user, for whom you needn't check for sudo permissions

HOSTNAME - your computer domain name

Any  mistakes you make when editing /etc/sudoers will make your sudo command stop working & you need to use grub mode to restore your PC.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this just set my username to run as sudo without checking for a password? I wouldn't want that. I want to set it up so that I don't require sudo access at all.